# Returning status of Bluemix container IP allocation as JSON

Tags: json, containers, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to better automate my deployment of containers using the [containers service available from IBM Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html#container_index). I'm currently at the point where I'd like to create a script to assign an IP address and then hit a REST endpoint to update the DNS entry.

Management of IP addresses can be done using the [IBM Containers plug-in](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html#container_cli_ov) with commands such as [`cf ic ip bind`](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__ip_bind). However, before executing that command, I'd like to know which IP addresses are available. This is commonly done with the [`cf ic ip list`](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__ip_list) command which has output that looks like this:
    Number of allocated public IP addresses: 8

```
Listing the IP addresses in this space...
IP Address      Container ID   
1.1.1.1       
1.1.1.2        
2.1.1.1      
2.1.1.2         deadbeef-aaaa-4444-bbbb-012345678912   
2.1.1.3        
2.1.1.4        
1.1.1.3       
2.1.1.5
```

This is useful output to a human, but requires a lot of extra munging for a script to handle. Is there a way to simply have this command return the JSON output that is probably coming from the API? For regular CloudFoundry commands we can use `cf curl` and get usable output, but there doesn't appear to be an analog here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [IBM Containers REST API](http://ccsapi-doc.mybluemix.net/) for that:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "X-Auth-Token: xxxxxxxx" --header "X-Auth-Project-Id: xxxxxxxx" "https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v3/containers/floating-ips?all=true"
```

Example of output is (for privacy purposes I modified output below):

```
[
    {
        "Bindings": {
            "ContainerId": null
        }, 
        "IpAddress": "111.111.1111.1111", 
        "MetaId": "607c9e7afaf54f89b4d1c926", 
        "PortId": null, 
        "Status": "DOWN"
    }, 
    {
        "Bindings": {
            "ContainerId": "abcdefg-123"
        }, 
        "IpAddress": "111.111.1111.1112", 
        "MetaId": "607c9e7afaf54f89b4d1c9262d", 
        "PortId": "8fa30c31-1128-43da-b709", 
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
    }, 
    {
        "Bindings": {
            "ContainerId": "abcdefg-123"
        }, 
        "IpAddress": "111.111.1111.1113", 
        "MetaId": "607c9e7afaf54f89b4d1c9262", 
        "PortId": "6f698778-94f6-43d0-95d1", 
        "Status": "ACTIVE"
    }, 
    {
        "Bindings": {
            "ContainerId": null
        }, 
        "IpAddress": "111.111.1111.1114", 
        "MetaId": "607c9e7afaf54f89b4d1c926", 
        "PortId": null, 
        "Status": "DOWN"
    }
]
```

To get token for `X-Auth-Token` and space ID for `X-Auth-Project-Id`:

```
$ cf oauth-token
$ cf space <space-name> --guid
```